# Error:(39) Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)

Tags: android, xml, parsing, android-xml

I know there are lots of questions about this, but I really don't see where I'm making a compilation error in XML text.

I'm currently testing MapView with buttons on it. So in design I dragged a button from the palette and placed it in the XML design and when I click build/run, I receive an error:

```
   Error:(39) Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)
```

My XML code:

```
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.markjacks.myapp.MapsActivity" >

<fragment

android:id="@+id/map"
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
map:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
map:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
map:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
map:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"/>


<Button
    android:id="@+id/GoToLive"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="46dp"
    android:text="< Live"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    map:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    map:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    map:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    map:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    map:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    map:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.03" />


   </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I only receive this "Error parsingXML: not well-formed" error when the Button is in XML, so it's nothing to do with the map fragment. So where's my compilation error?

Comment: Change `android:text="< Live"` to `android:text="&lt; Live"`

Comment: Oh you mean I'm not allowed to use "<" in text?

Comment: @iBEK: Right, `<` must be escaped in XML when not starting a `<tag/>`.  See [**Simplified XML Escaping**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46637835/290085).